# single-line strikethrough in tikz syntactic tree

Tags: tikz-qtree

Minimally, I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[8pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}

\begin{document}

\ex.
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\Tree[.CP Op$_c$ [.C' [.C is ] [.TopP \qroof{this task}.NP [.Top      
[.Top is ] [.TP \qroof{\textit{pro}}.NP [.T' [.T ] \qroof{this task}.vP ] ] ]   
] ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I want to draw a single-line strikethrough line on the word 'is' in C node. I tried adding \st{is} to the relevant node in order to create the strikethrough, but the tree wouldn't print. Any ideas how to do the strikethrough? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

you need to load package `soul` ...

```
\documentclass[8pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
\usepackage{soul}% <--- added

\begin{document}
%\ex.  what is this?
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\Tree[.CP Op$_c$ [.C' [.C \st{is} ] [.TopP \qroof{this task}.NP [.Top
[.Top is ] [.TP \qroof{\textit{pro}}.NP [.T' [.T ] \qroof{this task}.vP ] ] ]
] ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]